# How do I make a pandas datatimeindex into twice daily frequency?

Tags: pandas, time-series, datetimeindex

I have a pandas df that looks like this:

```
           Open_fut  Close_fut
Date                           
2017-05-12   20873.0    20850.0
2017-05-11   20887.0    20869.0
2017-05-10   20891.0    20888.0
2017-05-09   20943.0    20886.0
2017-05-08   21001.0    20943.0
```

My dates are `datetime64[ns]` and the other columns `float64`.

How can I make my time series so that `Open_fut` comes at `2017-05-12 09:30:00` and `Close_fut` at `2017-05-12 15:30:00` and so on for each day?

**EDIT:**

Ideally the new df would look like this:

```
                    fut  
Date                           
2017-05-12 09:30:00 20873.0
2017-05-12 15:30:00 20850.0
.
.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) with adding `times` by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
time1 = '09:30:00'
time2 = '15:30:00'

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index + pd.to_timedelta(time1),
                                      df.index + pd.to_timedelta(time2)],
                                      names=['date1','date2'])
print (df)
                                         Open_fut  Close_fut
date1               date2                                   
2017-05-12 09:30:00 2017-05-12 15:30:00   20873.0    20850.0
2017-05-11 09:30:00 2017-05-11 15:30:00   20887.0    20869.0
2017-05-10 09:30:00 2017-05-10 15:30:00   20891.0    20888.0
2017-05-09 09:30:00 2017-05-09 15:30:00   20943.0    20886.0
2017-05-08 09:30:00 2017-05-08 15:30:00   21001.0    20943.0
```

For your output is solution similar, only is used [`lreshape`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape.py#L857) for reshaping + [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
time1 = '09:30:00'
time2 = '15:30:00'

df['date1'] = df.index + pd.to_timedelta(time1)
df['date2'] = df.index + pd.to_timedelta(time2)                                   
df = pd.lreshape(df, {'date':['date1', 'date2'], 'fut':['Open_fut', 'Close_fut']}) 
df = df.set_index('date').sort_index()             
print (df)
                         fut
date                        
2017-05-08 09:30:00  21001.0
2017-05-08 15:30:00  20943.0
2017-05-09 09:30:00  20943.0
2017-05-09 15:30:00  20886.0
2017-05-10 09:30:00  20891.0
2017-05-10 15:30:00  20888.0
2017-05-11 09:30:00  20887.0
2017-05-11 15:30:00  20869.0
2017-05-12 09:30:00  20873.0
2017-05-12 15:30:00  20850.0
```

EDIT:

[`lreshape`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape.py#L857) is now undocumented, but is possible in future will by removed ([with pd.wide_to_long too](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15003#issuecomment-324625271)).

Possible solution is merging all 3 functions to one - maybe `melt`, but now it is not implementated. Maybe in some new version of pandas. Then my answer will be updated.

Comment: I like your `lreshape` solution ;-) !